# Returned data type information_schema.identifier does not match expected type

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, information-schema

I am getting this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
> DETAIL:  Returned type information_schema.sql_identifier does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function app.get_custom_task_fields(integer,character varying,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
> ```

To fix it, I need to know the type of `column_name`, `ordinal_position` and `data_type` in my query. Or more generally, what is the data type of columns in `information_schema.columns` and how do I convert `sql_identifier` to an 'outputable' format to get it out of my function?

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.get_custom_task_fields(sess_identity_id int
                                                     ,session_code_str varchar
                                                     ,sess_company_id int)
RETURNS TABLE(field_name varchar,ordinal_position integer,field_type varchar) 
AS $$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT t.column_name,t.ordinal_position,t.data_type
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as t
    WHERE table_name = 'task_custom' order by t.ordinal_position;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres (`SELECT version()`;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Question 1

> What is the data type of columns in `information_schema.columns`?

You can either look it up in the manual:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

Or you can ask Postgres directly (using the catalog table [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)):

```
SELECT attname, atttypid::regtype
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'information_schema.columns'::regclass
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

> ```
>  attname       | atttypid
> ---------------+----------------------------------
>  table_catalog | information_schema.sql_identifier
>  table_schema  | information_schema.sql_identifier
>  table_name    | information_schema.sql_identifier
> ...
> ```

#### Question 2

> And how do I convert `sql_identifier` to an 'outputable' format to get it out of my function?

To find out specifics of *any* data type:

```
SELECT typname, typtype  -- 'd' is for 'domain'
     , typbasetype::regtype
FROM   pg_type
WHERE  oid = 'information_schema.sql_identifier'::regtype;
```

> ```
>  typname        | typtype | typbasetype
> ----------------+---------+-----------
>  sql_identifier | d       | character varying
> ```

So the data type `information_schema.sql_identifier` is a [`DOMAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) on `varchar`. To find out possible casts:

```
SELECT casttarget::regtype, castcontext
FROM   pg_cast
WHERE  castsource = 'character varying'::regtype;
```

> ```
>  casttarget | castcontext
> ------------+------------
>  regclass   | i
>  text       | i
>  character  | i
>  ...
> ```

You can cast to a desired output type. But there is a ...

### Simpler solution

You don't need to know any of this. Just reference the data type of columns. [The manual about `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#AEN79604)

> The type of a column is referenced by writing `table_name.column_name%TYPE`.

Write your function like this and you can't go wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.get_custom_task_fields(sess_identity_id int
                                                    , session_code_str varchar
                                                    , sess_company_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE(field_name       information_schema.columns.column_name%TYPE
              , ordinal_position information_schema.columns.ordinal_position%TYPE
              , field_type       information_schema.columns.data_type%TYPE) AS
$FUNC$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.column_name, t.ordinal_position, t.data_type
   FROM   information_schema.columns t
   WHERE  t.table_name = 'task_custom'
   ORDER  BY t.ordinal_position;
END
$FUNC$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The column reference is converted to the underlying type at function creation time. You'll see notices informing you about that.

Answer (score 3):

Your easiest (and probably, safest) solution is to `CAST` the columns to the types you wish to return (using the `::` operator, or the `CAST(xx AS type)` function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_custom_task_fields(sess_identity_id int,session_code_str varchar,sess_company_id int)
RETURNS TABLE(field_name varchar,ordinal_position integer,field_type varchar) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT t.column_name    :: varchar
           , t.ordinal_position :: integer
           , t.data_type        :: varchar
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as t 
        WHERE table_name = 'task_custom' 
        ORDER BY t.ordinal_position;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: thanks, cast works. but I am trying to understand how information_schema works at a deeper level

Comment: actually, the data_type as `string` is not so useful to me as a number, this is why I would like to see if data_type is represented as integer in postgres internally and get the code of the type instead of a string

Comment: If you need the internal representation, don't look for `information_schema` but `pg_catalog` and all the [System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalogs.html) (the schema that holds the database information in its *internal postgresql-specific way*)